# TouchId, FaceId login for mobile Apps

Tags: oauth2, authentication, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, login, mobilesdk

One customer is asking for having the Mobile App authentication for External users sites using Communities with FaceId and TouchId, I have tried "Implementing Screen Locking and PIN protection" in the Connected App.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/01/getting-started-with-the-new-salesforce-mobile-sdk-for-ios.html

This is for activating the app for inactivity once the user is logged in, is there any way to configure TouchId for the first login?, I mean, as an option instead of the login page, use TouchId for log in.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no that is not possible.  Biometric is used to bypass Passcode, a Mobile SDK feature that adds an extra layer of security for the app.  It would be impossible for biometric to authenticate you on first login because that would require the users password is known/stored.  From a security perspective that is something that should never be done.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible creatung an Authorization provider set it to Apple and configure that in Salesforce.

https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/

Then configure the phone to access through Sign in with apple.
Once your User account has a Sign In With Apple auth provider associated, you will be able to use the feature - including FaceId or TouchId. But it is important to note that Apple may only provide a pseudonymous email address to us which will make linking the Apple identity to an existing Contact impossible.